# Align text with button in collapsible set jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a `button` in the `header` of `collapsible list` along with text. But I want the button to be placed at `rightmost side`. When I am trying to do that, the text and button are not aligned.

EDIT:The button with value `"setting"` is not aligned with the text `"filtered list"`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/puX9w/

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Which button will place.. Please give more explanation about your query

Comment: which button? the button in the menu is working and is placed at the right?

Comment: @Dineshkani the button with value "setting". Its not aligned with the text "filtered list"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/kNDf4/

**HTML :**

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3 data-position="inline">Filtered list             
                    <span style="float:right;" class="button-span"> <input type='button' data-theme='b'  value='Settings' data-mini='true' data-inline='true' data-icon='gear' data-icon-pos='top' id="show-content"/>
                    </span>
                </h3>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d">
                    <li><a href="#">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Avery Johnson</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bob Cabot</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Caleb Booth</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button-span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -7px !important;
}

.ui-btn-text {
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, I removed text from the button by using data-iconpos="notext", now the icon is not showing. What could be the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/kNDf4/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. yeah sure, you deserve a lot upvotes for helping everyone on jQuery mobile problems

Comment: Hi, But why the event delegation is not working on this element? http://jsfiddle.net/kNDf4/3/

Comment: This is a special case where bind needs to be used: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/23/ replace it with on and see what will happen

Comment: But if I am adding element dynamically, I need to use event delegation. In that case, I am using "on". But its not working. http://jsfiddle.net/PMrDn/24/